# Show today's birthday

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the script i placed underneath, but it should show me who's having birthday today. i have added a birthday in my sql table ion this format: 1985-06-03

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Last 10 Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");
    if (!$connect) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("apploymentdevs");
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo LIMIT 10");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

DB Table structure:

```
ID          INT11
FirstName   Varchar
LastName    Varchar
Department  Varchar
Birthday    Date     (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

Comment: please share your table structure. so we can understand your problem and resolve it.

Comment: Hi, i tried to add a piece of code into the select statement:

    if(date('m-d') == substr($birthday,5,5))

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo LIMIT 10 if(date('m-d') == substr($birthday,5,5")));

Comment: @Richard You can do this with MySQL. You just need to format the dates to exclude the year. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29255217/3000179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("apploymentdevs");
        $today_date = date('d');
$today_month = date('m');

        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` where DATE('dob_column') = $today_date && MONTH(`dob_column`) = $today_month");
    if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
    }else{
    echo "No one birthday on today enter code here";
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: Why include the year? This will bring back no results, unless someone was born on the same day (in the same year).

Answer (score 3):

Since, you will need to exclude the year, you can use the `MONTH` and `DAY` SQL functions like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAY(birthday) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Comment: you can try this also

if (date('m-d', strtotime($row['date'])) == date('m-d'))

//-- Today is my birthday! Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, format each date to be `MM-DD`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM demo 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, "%c-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%c-%d")
LIMIT 10
```

This will bring back results where the `MM-DD` of both `NOW()` and the `birthday` value are equal.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: This is what i got now, but i guess its not completetly correct:

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "Efv#*I!1");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("my_site_db");
            $results = mysql_query
("SELECT * FROM aevinew2_verjaardagen where date_format    (Geboortedatum, "%c-%d") = DATE_FORMAT)NOW(), "%c-%d")") ;

Comment: is `DATE_FORMAT)NOW(), "%c-%d")` a typo with copy and paste, or is your code actually that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE MONTH(`table_column`) = '".date('m')."' AND YEAR(`table_column`) = '".date('Y')."'");
```